# Correct Way to Check if Spotlight Has Indexed a Folder's Contents

Tags: terminal, spotlight, script, command-line

Okay, so I've written a script that uses `mdfind` to more quickly match files, however, I need to find the best way to check whether a target directory is indexed or not, so I can fall back to using `find` instead if I have to.

I'm assuming I'll need to use `mdls`, however this does still return information about non-index files and folders, just less of it. Is there a particular value I should query that will allow me to easily determine whether a file/folder has been index by Spotlight or not?

Comment: There are only two reasons why a folder will not be indexed. 1) Privacy settings 2) software failure of spotlight. Are you really looking to script around one or both of these two factors?

Comment: Yes; the script should be able to run on any folder, but since it deals with files that are *normally* indexed then I'm using `mdfind` to accelerate the search, but if it's going to fail then I need to know so I can use a fallback if necessary.